# Move cursor to the end of block

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Is there a way to move the cursor to the end of a block, like a `procedure`, `function`, or `try` block? I'm using CnPack components, too. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> does not work

Comment: what IDE do you use?

Comment: Delphi 102. Tokyo with latest version of CnPack. @VadimKotov